# Django gmane Syntax error

Tags: python, django

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .fsong import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social/fsong.py", line 1, in <module>
import gmane as g, networkx as x, pylab as p, numpy as n, os
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gmane/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from .networkEvolution import NetworkEvolution
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gmane/networkEvolution.py", line 9, in <module>
from .pca import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gmane/pca.py", line 79
def __init__(self,*metrics,final_dimensions=2,draw=False):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have installed django using pip and trying to run python manage.py migrate. I am facing the above error. Any one have faced this before? I am using OSX and python version is 2.7.10, Django version 1.9

Comment: show your manage.py file

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
    import os
    import sys

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "wedcraze.settings")from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: `if name == "main":` is this the same line printed or it is like this in  `manage.py` `if` `__name__` `==` "`__main__`"`: